# Agile methodology - How to have an effective sprint retrospective?

Tags: agile, scrum, retrospective, scrum-master

I am the scrum master in my scrum team. At the end of a sprint, we have a sprint retrospective, and we comment on what good things we noticed in the sprint. We also comment on the bad things and what we can do to improve our sprints.

I wanted to know if any of you are doing anything different that brings positive things to the team. I want to make the most out of my sprint retrospective.

I would appreciate it, if you give me some insight of how you run your sprint retrospective and what you find effective from it.

Comment: As written, your question is both a polling question and too open-ended to elicit a canonical answer. Can you reframe it as a more-targeted question?

Comment: Hi Tony, our site isn't for holding discussions, except in [chat]. If there is a problem you're facing in your sprints, why don't you ask about that instead? See the [faq] and [ask] for more guidance on how to formulate your question. If you need more help, just let us know.

Comment: Temporarily closing, however, feel free to continue to [edit] as per the above suggestions. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

The [Agile Retrospectives: Making Good Teams Great](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0977616649) by Esther Derby and Diana Larsen will answer all your questions about retrospectives.